# Emailing Product picture from contact form in hidden field

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to attach a picture to the email sent by a contact form so my client can see which product it is, it is a motor dealership so sometimes he has several of the same vehicle with a similar name.

What i've done so far is have a hidden input field that posts the file name to a form handler, my question is how can i handle the image so that it can be viewed as if it were a signature or showing in the email without having to open it.

Do I make a call to the database selecting the pic that is = to the picture name posted and the predefine it's destination before putting it in the `$Bodymessage`? or can is there some other neat trick?

Comment: you can add image link as mail template in $bodymessage.

Comment: but make sure your mail is not text/plain.

Comment: @ParthShah Since I'm not very good at all of this, any chance you could provide an example to give me an idea? I'd really appreciate it as I'm really trying to learn.

Comment: can you add your code???

Comment: yes, did you mean image link as in: `www.webaddress.co.za/upload/image`?

Comment: yes. So you have to add <img src="url_of_your_image_not_path"> and place this html in your mail.

Comment: @ParthShah When i added it like so

Comment: when or where????

Comment: @ParthShah When i added it like so `pic = $_POST['pic']` then called on  with `$Body .= "<img src='/upload/$pic' width='250' height='220'>";` I just end up with the html in the email.

Comment: i also tried `$pic = $_POST['pic']` then `$sql = SELECT pic FROM stock WHERE pic = '$pic'"; then `mysqli_query` then `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` then `$uppic = $row['pic']` `$picloc = "/upload/$uppic";` then using it in `$Body .= $picloc;`

Comment: I think you need to post your complete code over here. Only then I can help you.

Comment: @ParthShah added my code below

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting something like this

```
$to = 'to@example.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Request';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['from_email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['to_email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="imag_url_not_path">';
$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Oh I understand now, sorry

Comment: can i use `$_POST` in `$message .= '<img src="www.website.co.za/upload/$_POST[pic]">';`?

Comment: doesn't seem to work, i'm just getting the actual <img> tag back with the email

Answer (score 0):

```
 This is my form Handler: 

 <?php
 $stocknr = $_POST['snr'];
 $EmailFrom = $_POST['visitormail'];
 $EmailTo = "someone@email.com";
 $Subject = "Details -"." $stocknr";
 $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['visitor'])); 
 $Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['visitortel']));
 $Cell = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['visitorcel']));
 $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['visitormail'])); 
 $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['notes'])); 
 $trans = $_POST['trans'];
 $fuel = $_POST['fuel'];
 $desc = $_POST['desc'];
 $year = $_POST['year'];
 $brand = $_POST['brand'];
 $model = $_POST['model'];
 $price = $_POST['price'];
 $counter = $_POST['counter'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $uppic = $_POST['pic'];
 // validation
 $validationOK=true;
 if (!$validationOK) 
 {
 print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">"; 
 exit;
 }


$con=mysqli_init();
if (!$con)
{
die("mysqli_init_failed");
}
if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,$servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname))
{
die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT pic, stocknr FROM stock WHERE stocknr = '$stocknr'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$pic = $row['pic'];



// prepare email body text
$Body = '<html><body>';
$Body .= "Att Saayman Motors";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Please follow up on the following lead below generated by Details 
- "."$stocknr";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$body .= "<p class='header'>Requested Followup Information</p>";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Interested Person Details";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Cell: ";
$Body .= $Cell;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Vehicle Information";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Details :";
$Body .= $title;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Stocknr: ";
$Body .= $stocknr;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Price: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "R ";
$Body .= $price;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "";
$Body .= '<img src="http://www.saaymanmotors.co.za/upload/$pic">';
$Body .= '</body></html>';
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";

}
?>
```

This is my Contact form

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="/contactengine.php">
<?php

$sqli = "SELECT trans, fuel, description, counter, year, brand, model, 
stocknr, price, pic FROM stock WHERE stocknr = '$stocknr'";
// Perform Query
$resulti = mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulti);
$trans = $row['trans'];
$fuel = $row['fuel'];
$desc = $row['description'];
$year = $row['year'];
$brand = $row['brand'];
$model = $row['model'];
$price = $row['price'];
$counter = $row['counter'];
$picloc  = $row['pic'];           
$title = "$year "."$brand "."$model";

$trans = $trans;
$fuel = $fuel;
$desc = $desc;
$year = $year;
$brand = $brand;
$model = $model;
$price = $price;
$counter = $counter;
$picloc = $picloc;
$stocknr = $stocknr;
        ?>
<input type="hidden" name="snr" value="<?php echo $stocknr ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="trans" value="<?php echo $trans ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="fuel" value="<?php echo $fuel ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="<?php echo $desc ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $title ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="brand" value="<?php echo $brand ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="year" value="<?php echo $year ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="pic" value="<?php echo $picloc ;?>" />
        <table width="320px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="form_header" for="visitor">Name *</label>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
      <input class="form_input" type="text" name="visitor" maxlength="50" 
 size="30">   
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label class="form_header" for="visitorcel">Cellphone *</label>
 <table>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
     <input class="form_input" type="tel" name="visitorcel" maxlength="50" 
     size="30">    
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
 <label class="form_header" for="visitormail">Email Address *</label>
 <table>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
  <input class="form_input" type="email" name="visitormail" maxlength="80" 
  size="30">       
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label class="form_header" for="visitortel">Telephone Number</label>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
    <input class="form_input" type="tel" name="visitortel" maxlength="30" 
size="30">      
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign="top">
<label class="form_header" for="notes">Message *</label>
<table>
 <tr>
     <td valign="top">
    <textarea class="form_mes_input" name="notes" maxlength="1000" cols="25" 
  rows="6"></textarea>     
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td width="100" style="text-align:left">
 <input type="submit" class="button submit_button" value="Submit">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: try this line $Body .= '<img src="http://www.saaymanmotors.co.za/upload/'.$pic.'">';

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /usr/www/users/saayma/contactengine.php on line 86  for the line you suggested

Comment: I just echo your $Body variable and found its echoing image tag with $pic variable instead of value of $pic. So there might be some concat related issue in your code.